# Calculate the number of pyramid

Tags: java

I'm trying to calculate the sum of the numbers in my pyramid in java. For this, mathematical rule is 2+5+8+9. I mean first row+first number of second row+ second number of third row like that.

```
int[] numbers = { 2,5,7,1,8,3,6,0,9,4 };

       System.out.println("   " + numbers[0]);
       System.out.println("  " + numbers[1] + " " + numbers[2]);
       System.out.println(" " + numbers[3] + " " + numbers[4] + " " + numbers[5]);
       System.out.println("" + numbers[6] + " " + numbers[7] + " " + numbers[8] + " " + numbers[9]);
```

For example:

```
   2

  5 7

 1 8 3

6 0 9 4
```

How can I calculate `2+5+8+9` in Java?

Comment: add the numbers while forming your pyramid...

Comment: Is your pyramid represented as an array?

Comment: @Abhishek how can I do this in java code?

Comment: Please show some of your coding. Is this pyramid static or are you building it dynamicly? How is this pyramid stored?

Comment: @Nikolas Charalambidis No, how can i use array for like this pyramid?I mean numbers are different how can i write like this example

Comment: how you are printing the pyramid. please show the code.

Comment: @ Issac Saji  I couldnt print like this.How should I do for pritntling like this

Comment: @diad do you want to sum the row? I can't see the rule leading to `2+5+8+9`

Comment: @xenteros I want to sum maximum number of for each row.For this, mathematical rule is 2+5+8+9.I mean first row+first number of second row+  second number of third row like that

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way of calculating `2+5+8+9` is using Java build-in feature:

```
int result = 2+5+8+9;
```

You should construct your pyramid as a 2D array.

```
int[] numbers = { 2,5,7,1,8,3,6,0,9,4 };
int addedElements = 0;
int nextSize = 1;
ArrayList<int[]> pyramid = new ArrayList<>();
while(addedElements< numbers.size()) {
    int[] level = new int[nextSize++];
    for (int i = 0; i < nextSize - 1; i++) {
        level[i] = numbers[addedElements++];
    }
}
int result = 0;
//add maximum of each `int[]` in pyramid.
for (int[] array : pyramid) {
    int currentMax = array[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
        if (array[i] > currentMax) {
            currentMax = array[i];
        }
    result+=currentMax;
}
System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: I want to sum maximum number of for each row.For this, mathematical rule is 2+5+8+9.I mean first row+first number of second row+ second number of third row like that

Comment: Oh, I see. Could you please edit your question and add that crucial info to the question?

Answer (score 1):

Try the follwoing code :

```
int[] numbers = { 2,5,7,1,8,3,6,0,9,4 };
int index = 1;
int number = 2;
int result = numbers[0];

while (index < numbers.length) {
    result += numbers[index + number -2];   
    index += number;
    number += 1;
}

System.out.println(result);
```

But the whole whing would be much easier and clearer if you just put your pyramide into a 2 dimensional array.

```
int[][] numbers = { {2},
                    {5,7},
                    {1,8,3},
                    {6,0,9,4} };

int result = numbers[0][0];
for (int i = 1; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    result += numbers[i][i-1];
}

System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException gives error

Comment: It works but wrong calculates I think.Because 2+5+8+9=24 but it gives 26 result.

Comment: It gives always add more two of actual summation.There is sth wrong

Comment: Look your pyramid, on the second layer 7 is the biggest number, so it should be `2+7+8+9` which is 26

Comment: Yes, but the rule is first row+first number of second row+ second number of third row like that.Therefore I am triyng to calculate 2+5+8+9 not 7.

Comment: In your question you write `I want to sum maximum number of for each row.` So edit this please